Easier way to show finite simple extensions have only finitely many intermediate fields
I was reading this post that concerns the idea that simple finite field extensions have only finitely many intermediate fields between them. I'm wondering why the following method hasn't been proposed:
Let $F$ be a field and let $K/F$ be a simple and finite field extension. As $K$ is simple, $K=F(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha \in K$. Since $K$ is finite, then $[K:F] = \deg(m_{\alpha,F}(x))=n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. As $n$ has only finitely many divisors, then by the tower formula for fields, i.e. for $E$ satisfying $F \subseteq E \subseteq K$, we have
$$n = [K:F] = [K:E][E:F]$$
implies that we have only finitely many choices for $E$. What gives? Am I missing something here? I would think that if the answer were this simple (ha, no pun intended) then I would have seen this solution by now. Perhaps I'm mistaken.

You have shown that there are only finitely many possible degrees for an intermediate extension, not that there are only finitely many such extensions. A priori it could still be that there are infinitely many subextensions of, say, degree 2.

@BenSteffan ah yes. Thank you for the clarification

In addition to Ben's comment, note that your argument does not use that $K$ is simple! You only use that $K$ is finite. So your argument is "too good to be true": if it worked you would have proven the stronger claim that a finite extension has finitely many subextensions, which is false.
The famous counterexample here is $\mathbb{F}_p(x, y)$ as an extension of $\mathbb{F}_p(x^p, y^p)$, which is an extension of degree $p^2$ generated by two elements which has infinitely many subextensions of degree $p$; details can be found here.
